# extract value from subarray or return null using jq

Tags: json, command-line, jq

So given this input

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "tags": [
        {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "I am id 1"
        },
        {
            "Key": "Else",
            "Value": "Random"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "id": 2,
    "tags": null
}
```

I would like to get the `id` and the value of `name` if exists. So for that input, I would like to get the following output.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "I am id 1"
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": null
}
```

I tried doing:

```
jq '{"id": .id, "name": .tags[]|select(.Key=="Name").Value}'
```

but although it extracts when it that key is present, it fails to give `null` or default value when the path doesn't exist.

Any idea on how to solve this?

You can try out at this jqplay: https://jqplay.org/s/GgXZg67o79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using jq 1.5 or later

```
{id, name: (.tags | if . then from_entries.Name else . end )}
```

or if you have a sufficiently recent (post-1.6) version of jq, you can omit the `else .`:

```
{id, name: (.tags | if . then from_entries.Name end )}
```

### An alternative for jq 1.3 and up

```
{id, name: (.tags // {} | .[] | select(.Key=="Name").Value // null)}
```

See also the Comments below.

Comment: `{id, name: (.tags | if . then .[] | select(.Key=="Name").Value else null end)}` worked. Thanks for your insights @peak! Am I allowed to accept your answer even if it doesn't have the full solution?

Comment: What version of jq are you using?

Comment: I'm using jq-1.5

Comment: I've tested the `from_entries` version with jq 1.5 and jq 1.6. See update for earlier versions.